# Why is the Mask size mismatched in the Compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, masking

I masked an image in the UV/Image editor masking section. I then used that mask in the compositor for background replacement. However, the mask size seems to be different. Why is that? Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: On the dimensions controls, the resolution size is set up at 50%, bring that up to 100% or add a distort-scale node after the mask and before the alpha over and set it to render size.

Comment: That was part of it. The ratio was also off.

Answer (score 3):

The reason seems to be that the render resolution didn't match up with the image size.