# Mask not matching the image

Tags: masking, compositing-nodes

I made a video and created a mask around my mouth. The problem I have is that in the output of the compositor the mask is not matching the mouth like it is in the movie clip editor of the Masking tab.

Here is the Mask editor view
[image]

And here is the output of the compositing (pointed by red arrow). The mask is bigger than the source video used to create the mask.

[image]

Comment: Is the video clip the same size as the output dimensions for the project? Is the resolution set to 100%?

Comment: @susu yes, you are right. I fixed the issue by adding a scale node on the movie clip set on render size and it solve the problem. The reason is that the mask created in the Masking tab is done in the context of render size and not the input movie dimensions. Thanks again for your advise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Irregular mask size compositor vs movie clip editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94847/irregular-mask-size-compositor-vs-movie-clip-editor) and [why is the mask size mismatched in the compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30505/why-is-the-mask-size-mismatched-in-the-compositor)

Comment: [how can I resize the canvas of an image in the compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-can-i-resize-move-the-canvas-of-an-image-in-the-compositor/2404#2404)